# I'm receiving a NetworkX related error on Memgraph startup

Tags: python, networkx, memgraphdb

When I start Memgraph I can't access query modules. Right after the startup, I get `ImportError` for the NetworkX module. I've checked and I can see that I have NetworkX installed. I've also tried to reinstall Mmegraph but I had no luck. The error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the Python version. Memgraph is using the default system Python.

Check the Python version with `python --version`. If you don't run Python 3, upgrade it. With `python3` there shouldn't be such problems.